# Ansible SSH Key Setup

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm dipping my toes into Ansible and I'm having trouble configuring SSH keys.

I currently have two Ubuntu 14.04 VMs running and present in the Ansible hosts file.

I also have an extra VM which is being used for Ansible management.

I have created an SSH key on the management machine and 'ssh-copy-id' them to both of the Ubuntu 14.04 VMs.

Based on watching videos and following tutorials of Ansible configuration, I should now be able to run 'ansible instancegroupname -m ping' sequentially on both of the machines without having to enter a password.

However when running that command on the management VM, I am prompted to enter the SSH passphrase for the management VM itself, something I have not seen in the tutorial videos. It just seems to work for them?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Could you please add parameters -vvvv to your ansible parameters so that you can see what user is ansible using to connect to the hosts. By default it uses your current user.

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by adding the ssh-key to the ssh-agent.